# How to make request-bound data globally available in Ktor?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

I'm building a microservice in Ktor. While we are working within the application module, Ktor provides access to the `call` object which contains authorization data.

My problem is that I need to access the `call` object from a service-level class. In Spring, you would do this by accessing the `SecurityContext` which is globally available via a `ThreadLocal`. Ktor, being coroutine-driven, does not have that option.

Do I really need to pass down the `call` object through my service layer methods, or is there a way in Ktor to have some sort of "call context" object that you can access from anywhere?

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that coroutines do have a [`CoroutineContext`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/-coroutine-context/index.html) which is basically just a map.

Comment: The problem with `CoroutineContext` is that it is easy to lose it along the way (e.g. when calling `async`). In all those places, the coroutine context must be passed along *explicitly*, which is easy to forget (the compiler won't complain). But I do agree, with some discipline, this is a solution.

Comment: For anyone seeing this in the future, I have asked / answered a question about how to implement the coroutine context here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674112/access-coroutinecontext-element-via-key-class

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no build-in official opportunity at the moment.

I have written a Ktor-Feature, that implements that behaviour.
The answer is to complicated to describe it in a few words.

Check out the code + samples, if you are interested. Also an install guide is provided.

=> https://github.com/MaaxGr/ktor-globalcalldata

---

### Here a short snippet, what my dsl looks like:

Call suspending function test() directly or indirectly from a route:

```kotlin
routing {
    get("/test") {
        test()
        call.respond("OK")
    }
}
```

Access call object via `callData().call`

```kotlin
suspend fun test() {
    val url = callData().call.request.uri
    println(url) // prints "/test"
}
```

The library also allows to add custom properties that can be bound to the current coroutine/call.