# Access CoroutineContext element via Key class

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

In Ktor, I am hoping to implement some way to reference key value pairs inside a coroutineContext, without dragging references to objects around in method parameters. Based on https://proandroiddev.com/demystifying-coroutinecontext-1ce5b68407ad I have written my reference classes:

```
class MyElement(override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<*>, val value: String) : CoroutineContext.Element
class MyKey: CoroutineContext.Key<MyElement>
```

... // inside routing:

```
val key: CoroutineContext.Key<MyElement> = MyKey()
val ele = MyElement(key, "myJWT")
withContext(coroutineContext + ele) {
    val notNullEle : MyElement = coroutineContext[ele.key] as MyElement // not null
    logger.info(notNullEle.value) // "myJWT"
    val shouldNotBeNullEle = coroutineContext[MyKey()]// NULL!
}
val shouldBeNull = coroutineContext[ele.key] // is and should be null
val shouldBeNull2 = coroutineContext[MyKey()] // is and should also be null
```

When I send `ele.key` to `coroutineContext[ele.key]` I get the right element, but when I send a new instance of MyKey along, I get null, so the instance of MyElement is clearly mapped to the instance of the key. That does not work well for my purposes however, as I was hoping to get the instance of MyElement using the class of MyKey, since I would like to be able to, for instance, get the value in a HttpClient in the service layer without having to pass `ele.key` all the way down the chain. Is it possible?

What I am asking is basically the same as [How to make request-bound data globally available in Ktor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373266/how-to-make-request-bound-data-globally-available-in-ktor) which is unfortunately unanswered.

Comment: Consider a single `CoroutineContext.Element` which has a `Map` property, instead of trying to pack the key-value pairs each into their own elements.  (`CoroutineContext.Element`s aren't designed to have a lot of them in one context.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the article you linked, you could consider the `CoroutineContext` to be a `Map` with `CoroutineContext.Key` as its keys.

Given this premise the problem you are having is clear, `ele.key != MyKey()` or the keys are not equivalent by definition, so they will not return the same entry within the context Map.

This is the reason why most `CoroutineContext.Key` implementations are `object`, because that implements the `equals` method based on the object singleton. You will either need to also use `object` or correctly implement `equals` and `hashCode`.